# Do I need to build docker image on target machine

Tags: docker

When I build and run my image on my local ubuntu environment it worked as expected.

After that I pushed image to docker repo.

When I pulled image on target production machine on debian wheezy it was not working.

Only after I built image on target machine it started to work.

Why is this happening? I assumed that docker is targeting exactly this problem.

### specs:

#### local

```
Linux mans 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Client version: 1.3.1
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 4e9bbfa
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.1
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 4e9bbfa
```

#### production

```
Linux ci 3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.5-1~bpo70+1 (2014-11-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Client version: 1.3.1
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 4e9bbfa
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.1
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Gitcommit (server): 4e9bbfa
```

## edit

image built on ubuntu:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wormhit/docker-selenium-chrome/

When running:

```
Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
Starting Google Chrome ...
19:25:43.129 INFO - Launching a standalone server
19:25:43.483 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04
19:25:43.484 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-39-generic amd64
19:25:43.613 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
19:25:45.085 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
19:25:46.523 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
19:25:46.525 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
19:25:46.526 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
19:25:46.527 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
19:25:46.528 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
19:25:46.683 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@53058579
19:25:46.684 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
19:25:46.690 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
19:25:46.690 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@228690e3
```

image built on wheezy:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wormhit/msb-docker-selenium-chrome/

When running:

```
Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
Starting Google Chrome ...
19:35:05.405 INFO - Launching a standalone server
19:35:05.460 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04
19:35:05.461 INFO - OS: Linux 3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64 amd64
19:35:05.489 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
19:35:05.597 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
19:35:05.688 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
19:35:05.690 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
19:35:05.691 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
19:35:05.692 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
19:35:05.692 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
```

Comment: "Not working" is too vague a description to allow for diagnosis.

Comment: In short, though: (1) No, you should not need to build a docker image on the target machine. (2) We can't tell you why you saw contrary behavior without much, much more information -- ideally, a full reproducer. At **absolute minimum**, a description beyond "was not working" is called for.

Comment: @charles-duffy I don't want you guys to debug it. I want to know if that is something that you can encounter in everyday work with docker. On top of that should I just pull image on target machine and run it, or do I need to clone my repo and build it?

Comment: You don't even need to pull it. It gets pulled automatically. what did you push the image as and what did you pull it as?

Comment: I edited my question with more info.

Comment: @usman-ismail I know that it is pulled when you run it. This is absolutely not related to my question. And I don't understand your question. What do you mean with "what did you push the image as"? Can you specify that please?

Comment: People! If you down-vote I expect comment with info why you think this question is down-vote worthy!

Comment: In terms of debugging, by the way -- since your error appears to be that initialization doesn't complete, I'd want to set log levels to DEBUG across the board and/or use sysdig to watch what's going on -- if we're trying to grab a lock or open a socket and hanging, that's interesting information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question has been clarified in comments:

> I want to know if that is something that you can encounter in everyday work with docker.
>
> On top of that should I just pull image on target machine and run it, or do I need to clone my repo and build it?

- No, this is not a typical scenario encountered when using Docker. Any behavior within Docker responsible for this is likely to be considered a bug.
- Yes, you should be able to pull the image on the target machine and run it directly.